# What is the best approach of breaking long running stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, transactions

What is the best approach of breaking long running stored procedures (up to 20 minutes)?
Inside the Stored procedure is wrapped in a transaction. If I close connection will this transaction be rolled back? 
Another approach is to start a transaction in C# before I start the stored procedure and when I want to cancel the stored procedure I just need to rollback the C# transaction.

Comment: Are you trying to let the user decide, "hmm, it's been too long" and let him cancel it, or are you trying to cancel by policy "It's been 20 minutes, the call will be automatically cancelled"

Comment: I'm giving this opportunity to the users (actually it's a service with support of command cancellation).

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer to add my 2cent about transactions and asych

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you close the connection, SQL Server will rollback the transaction if it notices the disconnect before the transaction commits.  There'll be a (very) small time window where the transaction might complete just when you disconnect.

A custom transaction adds complexity and has few benefits for a single stored procedure call.  So I'd go for the disconnect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I decided to simply break the connection and allow to SQL Server to rollback the transaction itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a time out in three place-- the connection, the command, and if you are ultimately programming a web page-- in the page time out.

The relevant time out in this case is the *command time out*.

**Update**: Cancelling by a user's event:
To cancel your command by a user event, call Cancel() on the command. I haven't written code to test this, but I suspect that once you call ExecuteReader() it will block, so you'd need an async call-- BeginExecuteNonQuery(), which really is a pain to set up-- it requires extra things on the query string and I think it requires SQL2005+

**UPDATE**: Re: Transactions
C# (or ADO.NET) transaction code adds about two lines of code and guarantees invocations of stored procedures (which may have more than one statement in them, in not today, maybe a year from now) succeed or fail as a unit. They normally are not a source of poor performance and can be a source of poor performance when not used-- e.g. a long series of inserts runs faster in a transaction.

If you do not call CommitTrans() the transaction will rollback, you do not have to explicitly call Rollback()

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2008 R2, so it's not a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set Timeout   at the time of beginning the transaction.

Comment: I can't do it because sometimes such long operations are needed by business logic.